# Generate Random Number within range using Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have `ranges`, where each tuple represents the range of a random number. e.g:

`ranges = [(-1,100), (0,1), (50, 5000)]`

Now, I want to create a numpy array where each element of array is randomly generated from the corresponding tuple of `ranges`.

Pseudo code:

`rand_array = numpy.array[randomly generate element1 from (-1,100), randomly generate element2 from (0,1), randomly generate element3 from (50,500)]`

Of course, naive way to do this is:

`rand_array = [random.uniform(coord[0], coord[1]) for coord in ranges]`

But I want to do it in numpy way, as my whole code accepts numpy array data-types. Another solution can be to convert naively generated `rand_array` to `numpy` array. But I think it is not efficient. Is there a numpy way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most random functions accept array parameters. So you can do

```
np.random.uniform(*np.transpose(ranges))
```

The usual broadcasting rules apply, for example, to get 10 triplets

```
np.random.uniform(*np.transpose(ranges),(10,3))
```

Comment: thanks. How  to generate `x` number of elements in this way? is there a way to do this like this: `np.random.uniform(x, *np.transpose(ranges))`  (where `x` is an integer specifying numebr of elements or rows of numpy array). Sorry, I forgot to include that in question.